# Web page not save correctly in google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, html

When I try to save a web page using the format "Web Page, Complete," half of the time it only saves the the folder containing the style sheet and images, and the .html file is not saved anywhere on my hard drive. How do I correct this? I have noticed it also happens when I use Safari, so it is not just an isolated issue with Google Chrome.

Comment: Well how this question related to javascript and php ?

Answer (score -1):

First save the whole page (webpage,complete) which may only save the folder containing the style sheets and images, again press CTRL+S to save the page but this time select to save only the HTML page by clicking on- (webpage,HTML only).

Comment: In my case, result is exactly the same as just saving as "webpage, complete".

Answer (score -1):

When directory is saved but not the file, try the following:

1. In "File name:" include the .html extension (example:
   SampleFileName.html), and
2. Select Webpage, Complete in "Save as Type:"

Seems to fix the bug.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.